# Построение фразы с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли ошибки в предложении:

*"Беря на себя ответственность за чью-то жизнь — нельзя считать, что вам за это что-то будут должны."*

Корректно ли построение деепричастного оборота? Прошу ответить наиболее полно — почему в нём есть или отсутствует ошибка.

Comment: Хотя вопрос о пунктуации и не ставился, должен заметить, что тире здесь - чисто авторское. Обычно деепричастный оборот выделяется запятыми.

Answer (score 4):

Действие деепричастия/деепричастного оборота, как правило, относится к подлежащему данного предложения.

**Подведя итоги прений, председатель собрания отметил общность взглядов докладчика и участников совещания.** *( Здесь два действия, и их производитель одно лицо - председатель).*

> Если же производитель действия, обозначенного глаголом-сказуемым, и производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием, не совпадают, употребление деепричастного оборота стилистически ошибочно, например: **«Переходя через рельсы, стрелочника оглушил неожиданный свисток паровоза» (переходя относится к стрелочнику, а оглушил – к свистку).

Встречающиеся у писателей-классиков отступления от этой нормы представляют собой либо галлицизм, либо результат влияния народного языка, например:

**Поселившись теперь в деревне, его мечта и идеал были в том, чтобы воскресить ту форму жизни, которая была при деде (Л. Толстой)**

В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего:

2)       **в безличном предложении при инфинитиве, например:**

> **Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.**

Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически неоправданно, например.

**«Уезжая из родного города, мне стало грустно»; «Прочитав вторично рукопись, редактору показалось, что она нуждается в серьезной доработке».**

В вашем примере действие, выраженное деепричастием, относится к действию инфинитива безличного предложения: **нельзя считать.**

**Беря** на себя ответственность за чью-то жизнь - **нельзя считать,** что вам за это что-то будут должны.

**Поэтому ошибки в вашем предложении нет.**

См.: [Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по литературному редактированию](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02)